# Java: Extracting data from a website table

Tags: java, html, web, extract, data-extraction

I'm trying to skim data from the NYSE website. There's a table (though its not formatted like an HTML table, but rather with div's inside div's inside div's) with data points I want to analyze. So I have the following method to actually load and begin to parse the html:

```
public static void skim() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:JNJ");
    java.io.InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    int ptr = 0;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char)ptr);
        buffer.append((char)ptr);
    }

}
```

It works all well and good, but the problem is that the HTML it prints out is a little different from the HTML I see when I do inspect element. The actual data itself seems to be missing. So I guess it loads separately from the framework HTML. So how do I actually get the data points from the website? Is there a certain way I should be loading the webpage or what?

Comment: This is highly likely a mechanism on their end to prevent people like yourself from scraping data on their homepage. Why not do this the _proper_ way, and use [a provider that offers an API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10040996/1790644).

Comment: Web page scraping does not really work in the modern age unless you fully simulate a "headless" browser.  What you see in your browser bears little relation to the data returned from the initial HTTP GET request.  There's Javascript and AJAX and DOM manipulation and all sorts of other techniques to build the displayed page in your browser.  And as @MattClark says, they probably have deliberately made it very hard to "scrape".

Answer (score 0):

Just use yahoo finance. You can get the data off their website using this method, and then good luck on parsing the data...